# Convert float seconds to chrono::duration

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, c++-chrono

What is the easiest and elegant way to convert `float` time in seconds to `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano>`?

Is it just converting seconds to nanoseconds and passing to the `std::chrono::duration` constructor?

I have tried this code:

```
constexpr auto durationToDuration(const float time_s)
{
    // need to convert the input in seconds to nanoseconds that duration takes
    const std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano> output{static_cast<int64_t>(time_s * 1000000000.0F)};
    return output;
}
```

But it isn't converting well on many values of the input `time_s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is also the easiest **and** *safest*.  Safety is a key aspect of using chrono.  Safety translates to:  Least likely to contain programming errors.

There's two steps for this:

1. Convert the `float` to a `chrono::duration` that is represented by a `float` and has the period of `seconds`.
2. Convert the resultant `duration` of step 1 to `nanoseconds` (which is the same thing as `duration<int64_t, std::nano>`).

This might look like this:

```
constexpr
auto
durationToDuration(const float time_s)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using fsec = duration<float>;
    return round<nanoseconds>(fsec{time_s});
}
```

`fsec` is the resultant type of step 1.  It does absolutely no computation, and just changes the type from `float` to a `chrono::duration`.  Then the chrono engine is used to do the actual computation, changing one `duration` into another `duration`.

The `round` utility is used because floating point types are vulnerable to round-off error.  So if a floating point value is close to an integral number of nanoseconds, but not exact, one usually desires that close value.

But `std::chrono::round` is really a C++17 facility.  For C++14, just use one of the free, open-source versions floating around the web (http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html or https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h).